# Randomly getting java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77) sending message on RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

While sending message on RabbitMQ, I am getting following exception randomly

```
2021-05-26 11:31:03.274  INFO 6728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [<<My Server IP>>:5672]
2021-05-26 11:31:09.653  WARN 6728 --- [0.3.52.168:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Socket closed)
2021-05-26 11:31:09.660 ERROR 6728 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException] with root cause
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:330) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:275) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:373) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1139) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1087) ~[amqp-client-5.10.0.jar:5.10.0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:638) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:613) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:724) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2132) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2105) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1049) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1114) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1107) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.5.jar:2.3.5]
    at com.ukg.testbed.service.impl.RabbitMQSender.send(RabbitMQSender.java:23) ~[main/:na]
    at com.ukg.testbed.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl.createEmployee(EmployeeServiceImpl.java:42) ~[main/:na]
    at com.ukg.testbed.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77b5167b.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at com.ukg.testbed.service.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$70140a97.createEmployee(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.ukg.testbed.controller.EmployeeController.registerNewEmployee(EmployeeController.java:36) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

My code for sending

```
    @Service
    public class RabbitMQSender {
    
    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate kRabbitTemplate;
    
    @Value("${rmq.test.exchange}")
    private String exchange;
    
    @Value("${rmq.test.routingkey}")
    private String routingkey;  
    
    public void send(EmpDTO empDTO) {
        System.out.println("Sending msg = " + empDTO);
        kRabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingkey, empDTO);
        System.out.println("Sent msg = " + empDTO);     
    }
    }
```

And this is the config :

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Value("${rmq.test.queue}")
    String queueName;

    @Value("${rmq.test.exchange}")
    String exchange;

    @Value("${rmq.test.routingkey}")
    private String routingkey;

    @Bean
    Queue kQueue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange kExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding kBinding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingkey);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter kJsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate kRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate kRabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        kRabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(kJsonMessageConverter());
        return kRabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

I have checked following

1. Disk / CPU / Memory Utilization are ok on server
2. Maximum time connection is established so ruling out config issues.

This has been very frequent for multiple queues in Production env.

This is also happening for flows where we send message in Transaction.

```
 "Caused By": {
      "com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException: Continuation call for method #method<tx.commit>() on channel AMQChannel(amqp://myvhost@<RMQHOST>:5672/myvhost,1) (#1) timed out": ["AMQChannel.java", 313, "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrapTimeoutException", "AMQChannel.java", 295, "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc", "AMQChannel.java", 141, "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc", "ChannelN.java", 1540, "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit", "ChannelN.java", 52, "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit", "", -1, "sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor435.invoke", "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java", 43, "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke", "Method.java", 498, "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke", "CachingConnectionFactory.java", 1190, "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke", "", -1, "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy941.txCommit", "RabbitResourceHolder.java", 153, "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll"],
      "Caused By": {
        "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException": ["BlockingCell.java", 77, "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get", "BlockingCell.java", 120, "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet", "BlockingValueOrException.java", 36, "com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue", "AMQChannel.java", 502, "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply", "AMQChannel.java", 293, "com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc"]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Probably best to ask questions like this on the rabbitmq-users Google group. The RabbitMQ engineers don't monitor Stack Overflow closely.

Comment: ok, I will do that. But I need to help to find out that why In
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection() 
(this.connection.target == null) randomly , when there is a connection established already ?

Comment: The `target` gets set to `null` just before we call `createConnection` if we detect that the previous connection is no longer open when we try to create a new channel. I suggest you look at the server logs to see if there are any clues as to why it was closed and why the new connection could not be established.

Comment: Thanks for explaining !! Messages are getting lost, If “transaction synchronization” added by Spring-AMQP’s gets some network timeout exception during afterCommit() phase,
In our case "Continuation call for method #method<tx.commit>() on channel ..... timeout".
Can you please suggest how to prevent this on client end.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `RetryTemplate` to the `RabbitTemplate` to retry sends when there are connection problems.

As I commented, you should check the server logs to see if there are clues for the failure.

**EDIT**

This test shows it works as expected:

```java
@Test
public void testRetryOnCommitException() throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory mockConnectionFactory = mock(ConnectionFactory.class);
    final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    Connection mockConnection = mock(Connection.class);
    Channel mockChannel = mock(Channel.class);

    given(mockConnectionFactory.newConnection(any(ExecutorService.class), anyString())).willReturn(mockConnection);
    given(mockConnection.isOpen()).willReturn(true);
    given(mockConnection.createChannel()).willReturn(mockChannel);

    willAnswer(invocation -> {
        count.incrementAndGet();
        throw new IOException("commitFailed");
    }).given(mockChannel).txCommit();

    SingleConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SingleConnectionFactory(mockConnectionFactory);
    connectionFactory.setExecutor(mock(ExecutorService.class));
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setChannelTransacted(true);
    template.setRetryTemplate(new RetryTemplate());
    try {
        template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar", "baz");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        assertThat(e.getMessage()).contains("commitFailed");
    }
    assertThat(count.get()).isEqualTo(3);
}
```

**EDIT2**

This test simulates your `ChannelContinuationTimeoutException` problem:

```java
    @Test
    public void testRetryOnCommitException() throws Exception {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setChannelRpcTimeout(1);
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setChannelTransacted(true);
        template.setRetryTemplate(new RetryTemplate());
        assertThatExceptionOfType(AmqpIOException.class).isThrownBy(() -> template.convertAndSend(ROUTE, "commitError"))
                .withCauseExactlyInstanceOf(ChannelContinuationTimeoutException.class);
    }
```

And in the debugger, I see the send being tried 3 times, as expected.

And here are debug logs...

```
2021-06-10 09:23:20,135  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.junit.LogLevelsCondition [main] : +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Begin testRetryOnCommitException
2021-06-10 09:23:20,169 DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate [main] : Retry: count=0
2021-06-10 09:23:20,175  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory [main] : Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
2021-06-10 09:23:20,185  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory [main] : Created new connection: SpringAMQP#706ddbc8:0/SimpleConnection@6397248c [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53720]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,199 DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate [main] : Executing callback RabbitTemplate$$Lambda$548/0x0000000800cffdb8 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@2d2b6960 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@6397248c [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53720]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,199 DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate [main] : Publishing message [(Body:'commitError' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=11, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, deliveryTag=0])] on exchange [], routingKey = [test.queue.RabbitTemplateIntegrationTests]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,204  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory [main] : Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
09:23:20.206 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] WARN  c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
2021-06-10 09:23:20,211  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory [main] : Created new connection: SpringAMQP#706ddbc8:1/SimpleConnection@76ff68c5 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53721]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,213 DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate [main] : Checking for rethrow: count=1
2021-06-10 09:23:20,213 DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate [main] : Retry: count=1
2021-06-10 09:23:20,213 DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate [main] : Executing callback RabbitTemplate$$Lambda$548/0x0000000800cffdb8 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@2d2b6960 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@76ff68c5 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53721]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,213 DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate [main] : Publishing message [(Body:'commitError' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=11, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, deliveryTag=0])] on exchange [], routingKey = [test.queue.RabbitTemplateIntegrationTests]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,216  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory [main] : Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
09:23:20.216 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] WARN  c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
2021-06-10 09:23:20,226  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory [main] : Created new connection: SpringAMQP#706ddbc8:2/SimpleConnection@1da1380b [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53722]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,228 DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate [main] : Checking for rethrow: count=2
2021-06-10 09:23:20,228 DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate [main] : Retry: count=2
2021-06-10 09:23:20,228 DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate [main] : Executing callback RabbitTemplate$$Lambda$548/0x0000000800cffdb8 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@2d2b6960 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@1da1380b [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53722]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,228 DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate [main] : Publishing message [(Body:'commitError' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=11, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, deliveryTag=0])] on exchange [], routingKey = [test.queue.RabbitTemplateIntegrationTests]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,231  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory [main] : Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
09:23:20.232 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] WARN  c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
2021-06-10 09:23:20,239  INFO org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory [main] : Created new connection: SpringAMQP#706ddbc8:3/SimpleConnection@2accaec2 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 53723]
2021-06-10 09:23:20,240 DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate [main] : Checking for rethrow: count=3
2021-06-10 09:23:20,240 DEBUG org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate [main] : Retry failed last attempt: count=3
```

Comment: I checked the server logs and found this error :
Error on AMQP connection <0.14285.4931> (publicIP:50562 -> IP:5672 - connectionFactory#722cd0a9:3, vhost: '<OUR_URL>', user: '<OUR_URL>', state: running), channel 33:
operation tx.rollback caused a connection exception channel_error: "unexpected command while processing 'tx.commit'"

These logs suggest that RabbitMQ was trying to commit the message, but before it could do so, A rollback request was received from client.

Comment: Can retry template retry sends if failure/exception occurs in spring transaction when synchronizations commit the message on RabbitMQ?
If yes then Is there any document for how to use it?

If retry template can't work on spring transaction failure case, then is there any callback to which we can hook and retry from our code?

Comment: I don't see how the framework can send a rollback while the commit is in process; commit is a blocking operation. Yes, the `RetryTemplate` will work when the commit fails. https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#template-retry

Comment: I tried `RetryTemplate`, on my code , I used `execute` method with `RetryCallback` and `RecoveryCallback` arguments, My channel was transacted and flow was in spring transaction,  in `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(Method)`, I throw IO exception if `m.protocolMethodName()` contains "commit".

So message wasn't send because of the exception, but with retry template didn't work on this case.

If needed I can share more details on new github issue.

Comment: Don't open an issue unless or until we dermine there is a bug; please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Code too large to share on comment so created a gist
https://gist.github.com/kuldeepkalassts/5d977812862202552cdbd49d561f6bc3

I have used RetryTemplate.execute method, and deliberately created exception in privateRpc method.

I have shared the all files required

Comment: It's better in the form of an MCVE (minimal and complete) not just code snippets.

Comment: We have a method that send message in spring trx.
we use retryTemplate.execute to send, RetryTemplate bean is created with  ExponentialBackOffPolicy
In com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(Method) we throw an IOException at first line if protocolMethodName is commit.
This exception should cause failure in message sending, so there should be some retry, and then after RecoveryCallback should work.
But In our example this is not working. 
Git project link : https://github.com/kuldeepkalassts/testbed

Comment: This is hardly a "minimal" example; it needs to be stripped down to the bare minimum;  I don't have time to navigate all that code; I also don't see any tests that send any data, just a `contextLoads()` test. I have added a test to my answer that shows it working as expected.

Comment: I suggest you figure out why you are getting a `ChannelContinuationTimeoutException` - the default timeout is 10 minutes!!!!!! If you haven't reduced that to a small value, perhaps you should contact the RabbitMQ engineers on their Google group.

Comment: I added another test which works with the `ChannelContinuationTimeoutException` too.

Comment: I am concern about, why retry template is not working if there is an exception when spring transaction synchronization is trying to commit rabbitMQ message in afterCompletion phase.

Comment: I added logs showing it does work when the Rabbit transaction is primary. If you are using transaction synchronization, secondary transactions cannot cause the overall transaction to fail, since the primary transaction is already committed - it is "best effort 1PC").

Comment: To get more control don't use transaction synchronization; use 2 discrete transactions and if the secondary commit fails, perform a compensating transaction to reverse the commit of the primary transaction.

Comment: As per my understanding ChannelContinuationTimeoutException is caused by RPCTimeout, I am not sure about other reason. This RPCTimeout is not for 10 minutes. It is only for 5 seconds by default in our case ( As I seen in debugger).

So which timeout field you are suggesting for ChannelContinuationTimeoutException ?

Comment: The default is 10 minues `DEFAULT_CHANNEL_RPC_TIMEOUT = (int) MINUTES.toMillis(10)` - if you are seeing 5 seconds, you must be setting it. See my second test; it (mostly) causes `ChannelContinuationTimeoutException` - see `connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setChannelRpcTimeout(1);`.