# RabbitMQ : Channel shutdown: connection error reply-code=504, reply-text=CHANNEL_ERROR

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We are repeatedly facing the following error in our RabbitMQ client logs, where the channel get closed

> Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=504, reply-text=CHANNEL_ERROR - unexpected command while processing 'tx.commit', class-id=90, method-id=30)

Around the similar time the RabbitMQ logs show the following error

> operation tx.rollback caused a connection exception channel_error: "unexpected command while processing 'tx.commit'"

As per AMQP specification the 504 error occurs when client attempted to work with a channel not correctly opened.

Some post point that channel cache size should be increased to avoid this condition as code must be churning a lot of channels

We are using "channelCacheSize" value="25" in the connectionfactory object.

Questions

1. What is the probable root cause of this issue?
2. If we need to further increase channel cache size what is the optimum number?
3. And since we using RabbitMQ transacted publishing, messages sent here are getting lost?

Comment: I have seen this after a `ChannelContinuationTimeoutException` on the `txCommit` call - Spring will try to abort the transaction (and the commit is still in progress). We never got to the root cause of the timeout, however. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67701771/randomly-getting-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-at-com-rabbitmq-utility-b

Comment: This Channel shutdown: connection error reply code 504 error is generating from RabbitMQ Spring client libraries. What will be the exception type for this error? Is it com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException ?

Comment: Yes, that is the exception type.